# JAVA - ¿Como hacer un ranking (nombre-nota)?

Tags: java

Quiero hacer un "ranking" donde el usuario va ingresando nombre y nota de los alumnos, y al terminar el `while` ingresando 0 como nota, que se listen ej:

> 1) pepito: 10
>
> 2) pedro: 9
>
> 3) alex: 3

Acá los agrego a dos listas, nombres y notas pero no se como hacer después para ordenarlos y vincularlos... help!

```
   package tp02;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class ejercicio {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
             List<String> nombres = new ArrayList<String>();
             List<Integer> notas = new ArrayList<Integer>();
             int nota = 1;

        while (nota != 0) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese nombre: ");
            String nombre = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese nota: ");
            nota = input.nextInt();
            nombres.add(nombre);
            notas.add(nota);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sabes usar objetos? porque seria mas facil una sola lista con un objeto que tenga nombre y nota ;)

Comment: todavia no lo aprendi en la facultad.. pero si no es tan complicado de hacer me gustaria que explicaras como es!

Comment: Lo correcto es usar objetos como comenta gbianchi, te sugiero revises : https://guru99.es/java-oops-class-objects/

Comment: Supongamos que lo hacemos sin objetos (que se puede), aprendiste algun algoritmo para ordenar? buscaste alguno?

Comment: Collections.sort(notas); es el unico que se que ordena de menor a mayor. o alreves Collections.sort(notas, Collections.reverseOrder());

Comment: Pero aca no tenes una coleccion. No aprendiste a ordenar manualmente de ninguna forma?

Comment: Si quieres algo mas complejo pero que te funcionara, prueba las [colas de prioridad](http://pilascolasenjavaestructuradedatos.blogspot.com/2016/05/colas-con-prioridad-en-java.html)

Comment: @Mr.ToxicMan es correcto la forma como deseas ordenarlos pero debes usar un objeto y revisa mi respuesta como implementar un comparador para que se ordenen como lo deseas, de mayor a menor, saludos!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mas allá que las dos respuestas son excelentes y cubren lo que se debería hacer, voy a explicar la versión "principiante", sin usar objetos y haciendo un `sort` manual.

Una vez que cargaste las dos listas, estas están "sincronizadas", eso quiere decir que para el mismo indice de las dos, los datos se relacionan. Si ingresaste "pepe" en el indice 0 de la lista de nombres, el indice 0 de la lista de notas tiene la "nota" de pepe.

Entonces, lo que tenemos que hacer es ordenar la lista de notas, pero al mismo tiempo ordenando la lista de nombres.

Para ello, vamos a utilizar el algoritmo de orden mas simple que hay, burbujeo, que va recorriendo la lista y ordenando, hasta que termina de ordenarla.

El algoritmo es simplemente así:

```
mientras (ordenealgo)
    ordenealgo = false
    recorrer desde 0 (x) hasta tamañolista-1
        comparo posx con posx+1
            ordeno si corresponde
            pongo ordenealgo en true
    termino recorrer
termino mientras
```

entonces, en codigo, tu algoritmo para las dos listas seria asi:

```
int nNota = 0;
string nNombre = "";
boolean ordene = true;
while ordene {
    ordene = false;
    for (int i=0; i<notas.length-1; i++) {
        if (notas.get(i) > notas.get(i+1)) {
            nNota = notas.get(i+1);
            notas.set(i+1,notas.get(i));
            notas.set(i,nNota);
            //y hacemos lo mismo con el nombre
            nNombre = nombres.get(i+1);
            nombres.set(i+1,nombres.get(i));
            nombres.set(i,nNombre);
            //y ponemos la bandera en true, porque hubo un cambio
            ordene = true;
        }
    } 
}
```

O sea que luego de llenar las listas, ordenas con este algoritmo, y luego ya puedes mostrar.

Answer (score 4):

La forma adecuada de realizar lo que deseas es crear una lista de objetos que contenga la propiedad `nombre` y `nota`, para esto debes crear primeramente un objeto:

```
public class Nota {
    private String nombre;
    private int nota;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getNota() {
        return nota;
    }

    public void setNota(int nota) {
        this.nota = nota;
    }    

}
```

ahora, me parece que sería más adecuado que el usuario definiera la cantidad de usuarios y poder introducir estos usuarios definiendo su `nombre` y `nota` para almacenarlos en un `ArrayList`:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

List<Nota> notas = new ArrayList<Nota>();
Nota notaUsuario = null;
String valorNombre;
int valorNota;

System.out.println("Ingrese numero de usuarios: ");
int numeroUsuarios = input.nextInt();
int counter = 0;
while (counter < numeroUsuarios) {
    //Crea nuevo objeto.
    notaUsuario = new Nota();
    System.out.println("Ingrese nombre: ");
    valorNombre = input.next();
    notaUsuario.setNombre(valorNombre); 
    System.out.println("Ingrese nota: ");            
    valorNota = input.nextInt();
    notaUsuario.setNota(valorNota);

    //Agrega objeto usuario a ArrayList
    notas.add(notaUsuario);
    //Incrementa contador.
    counter++;
}
```

al obtener la lista de objetos nota puedes usar este método para ordenarlos de mayor a menor:

```
   Collections.sort(notas, new Comparator<Nota>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Nota nota1, Nota nota2){
        return  nota2.getNota() - nota1.getNota();
    }
   });
```

ahora al obtener el ordenamiento, puedes imprimirlos como lo deseas:

```
   for(int i = 0; i <notas.size(); i++){
           System.out.println( (i+1) + ") " +  notas.get(i).getNombre() + ": " + notas.get(i).getNota());           
   }
```

---

Ejemplo  de salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

código completo:

```
public class ejercicio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        List<Nota> notas = new ArrayList<Nota>();
        Nota notaUsuario = null;
        String valorNombre;
        int valorNota;

        System.out.println("Ingrese numero de usuarios: ");
        int numeroUsuarios = input.nextInt();
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter < numeroUsuarios) {
            //Crea nuevo objeto.
            notaUsuario = new Nota();
            System.out.println("Ingrese nombre: ");
            valorNombre = input.next();
            notaUsuario.setNombre(valorNombre); 
            System.out.println("Ingrese nota: ");            
            valorNota = input.nextInt();
            notaUsuario.setNota(valorNota);

            //Agrega objeto usuario a ArrayList
            notas.add(notaUsuario);
            //Incrementa contador.
            counter++;
        }

        // Sorting
       Collections.sort(notas, new Comparator<Nota>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Nota nota1, Nota nota2){
            return  nota2.getNota() - nota1.getNota();
        }
       });

       //Imprime valores ordenados
       for(int i = 0; i <notas.size(); i++){
           System.out.println( (i+1) + ") " +  notas.get(i).getNombre() + ": " + notas.get(i).getNota());           
       }       

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

te envió ejemplo un objecto

Primero creamos un onjecto de nombre alumnos

este objecto tiene 2 atrubutos nombre y nota, donde almacenaremos los datos ingresados por pantalla.

```
public class Alumnos implements Comparable<Alumnos>{

    private String nombre;
    private Integer nota;

    public Alumnos(){}

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public Integer getNota() {
        return nota;
    }
    public void setNota(Integer nota) {
        this.nota = nota;
    }

     @Override
     public int compareTo(Alumnos o) {
         if (nota < o.nota) {
             return -1;
         }
         if (nota > o.nota) {
             return 1;
         }
         return 0;
     }    
}
```

dentro de esta clase debemos implementa la interfaz Comparable, esta clase deberá implementar el método public interface compareTo, el cual sirve para comparar un objeto contra otro, este método recibe como parámetro otro objeto, el cual utilizaremos para comprarlo contra el actual para responder con un entero, el cual deberá ser:

< 0 (Menor que cero): cuando el objeto actual es menor que el otro
= 0 (Igual a cero): cuando los objetos son iguales

> 0 (Mayor que cero): cuando el otro objeto es mayor.

Cuando una clase implementa Comparable entonces podemos decir que está preparada para ser Ordenada y ordenarla será tan simple como hacer lo siguiente:

Collections.sort(listAlumnos);

Asumiendo que la variable listAlumnos es una lista de objetos que implementan Comparable.

ahora en la clase main creamos el código para que el usuario ingresa los datos a comparar, cabe señalar que se saldrá del while cuando la nota es = 0.

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    List listAlumnos = new ArrayList();
    Alumnos alum = new Alumnos();
    int nota = 1;

```
while (nota != 0) {
    alum = new Alumnos();
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese nombre: ");
    alum.setNombre(input.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Ingrese nota: ");
    alum.setNota(input.nextInt());
    listAlumnos.add(alum);
    nota = alum.getNota();
    System.out.println("----------");
}

Collections.sort(listAlumnos);
imprimeListaAlumnos(listAlumnos);
```

}

por ultimo creamos un método que nos permita imprimir la lista.

```
public static void imprimeListaAlumnos(List<Alumnos> listAlum) {
        for (Alumnos alumnos : listAlum) {
            System.out.println("nombre : "+alumnos.getNombre()+"   nota :  "+alumnos.getNota());
        }
    }
```

salida por pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero sea de tu ayuda saludos.

Comment: La respuesta esta perfecta. Pero tene en cuenta que el usuario esta en la facultada aprendiendo, tal vez seria mejor una respuesta con un sort simple sobre las dos listas. No vio clases, menos interfaces.